# VBscript to list applied patches in the last 24 hours

Tags: vbscript

I have a VB script that reads from a text file, a list of servers.  It then searches for the last windows update patch that was applied.  I need this to list any patches in the last 24 hours.  I have it piped to a text file which I will list here.  Here is my code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("servers.txt", 1)
server = ""
On Error Resume next

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  server = line
' 'wscript.echo server
  Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", server)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo server & " Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number) & " Source: " &  Err.Source & " Description: " &  Err.Description
    WScript.Echo server & " Communications Error"
    Err.Clear
  Else
      Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
      Set colHistory = objSearcher.QueryHistory(0, 1)
      For Each objEntry in colHistory
        Wscript.Echo server & " "
'       Wscript.Echo "Operation: " & objEntry.Operation 
'       Wscript.Echo "Result code: " & objEntry.ResultCode 
'       Wscript.Echo "Exception: " & objEntry.Exception 
        Wscript.Echo "Date: " & objEntry.Date 
        Wscript.Echo "Title: " & objEntry.Title 
'       Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objEntry.Description 
'       Wscript.Echo "Unmapped exception: " & objEntry.UnmappedException 
'       Wscript.Echo "Client application ID: " & objEntry.ClientApplicationID 
'       Wscript.Echo "Server selection: " & objEntry.ServerSelection 
'       Wscript.Echo "Service ID: " & objEntry.ServiceID 
        i = 1 
      Next
  End If
Loop

file.Close
```

Here is some sample output:

```
hercules 
Date: 7/10/2014 3:26:22 PM
Title: Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2971850)
ares 
Date: 7/16/2014 3:56:01 PM
Title: Security Update for Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 Edition (KB2973201)
pheme 
Date: 7/15/2014 8:04:04 PM
Title: Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - July 2014 (KB890830)
```

Is there another way instead of using the 
`objSearcher.QueryHistory(0, 1)`? That only lists the last update.  I need it to list any patches applied in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("servers.txt", 1)
server = ""

Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  line = file.Readline
  server = line
' 'wscript.echo server
  Set objSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session", server)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    'WScript.Echo server & " Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number) & " Source: " &  Err.Source & " Description: " &  Err.Description
    WScript.Echo server & " Communications Error"
    Err.Clear
  Else
      Set objSearcher = objSession.CreateUpdateSearcher
      Set colHistory = objSearcher.QueryHistory(0, 1)
    For Each objEntry In colHistory
    If DateDiff("h", objEntry.Date, Now) <= 24 Then
        Wscript.Echo server & " "
        'Wscript.Echo "Operation: " & objEntry.Operation
        'Wscript.Echo "Result code: " & objEntry.ResultCode
        'Wscript.Echo "Exception: " & objEntry.Exception
        Wscript.Echo "Date: " & objEntry.Date
        Wscript.Echo "Title: " & objEntry.Title
        'Wscript.Echo "Description: " & objEntry.Description
        'Wscript.Echo "Unmapped exception: " & objEntry.UnmappedException
        'Wscript.Echo "Client application ID: " & objEntry.ClientApplicationID
        'Wscript.Echo "Server selection: " & objEntry.ServerSelection
        'Wscript.Echo "Service ID: " & objEntry.ServiceID
    End If
  Next
  End If
Loop

file.Close
```

Comment: This works, but it seems its only doing this for the 1st server in the list??

Answer (score 0):

inside the **For Each** iteration place the below code.

```
If DateDiff("h", objEntry.Date, Now) > 24 Then Exit Do End If
```

Comment: do I put that here:  For Each objEntry in colHistory
 If DateDiff("h", objEntry.Date, Now) > 24 Then Exit Do End If